# Keras/TensorFlow MNIST DCGAN: why does generator has almost zero loss from start?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mnist, generative-adversarial-network, dcgan

I have constructed a DCGAN (deep convolutional generative adversarial network) inspired by [this github repository](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow). It is written in a more low level Tensorflow code that I tried transforming into Keras syntax instead.

Now, the network is quite heavy I think (around 4 million parameters), and I get this problem that during training that the generator network beats the discriminator network by *a lot*. I have not found any similar posts about this problem, since most of the time it is the discriminator that beats the generator (when in fact being fooled), or that we have *mode collapse*. So I am thinking there might be something wrong in the code (maybe the discriminator network is training when it shouldn't, or the loss function is wrong etc.). I have tried spotting the mistake but failed.

My code follows below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, ReLU, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization as BN#, tanh, sigmoid
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from keras.datasets import mnist
import time

import numpy as np
import math

from utils import load_mnist, load_lines, load_celebA


class dcgan(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        """
        Args:
        batch_size: The size of batch. Should be specified before training.
        y_dim: (optional) Dimension of dim for y. [None]
        z_dim: (optional) Dimension of dim for Z. [100]
        gf_dim: (optional) Dimension of G filters in first conv layer. [64]
        df_dim: (optional) Dimension of D filters in first conv layer. [64]
        gfc_dim: (optional) Dimension of G units for for fully connected layer. [1024]
        dfc_dim: (optional) Dimension of D units for fully connected layer. [1024]
        c_dim: (optional) Dimension of image color. For grayscale input, set to 1. [3]
        """

        self.build_model(config)

    def build_model(self,config):

        self.D = self.discriminator(config)
        self.G = self.generator(config)

        self.GAN = Sequential()
        self.GAN.add(self.G)
        self.D.trainable = False
        self.GAN.add(self.D)


    def discriminator(self,config):


        input_shape = (config.x_h,config.x_w,config.x_d)

        D = Sequential()

        D.add(Conv2D(filters=config.df_dim,strides=2,padding='same',kernel_size=5,input_shape=input_shape))
        D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        D.add(Conv2D(filters=config.df_dim*2,strides=2,padding='same',kernel_size=5))
        D.add(BN(momentum=0.9,epsilon=1e-5))
        D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        D.add(Conv2D(filters=config.df_dim*4,strides=2,padding='same',kernel_size=5))
        D.add(BN(momentum=0.9,epsilon=1e-5))
        D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        D.add(Conv2D(filters=config.df_dim*8,strides=2,padding='same',kernel_size=5))
        D.add(BN(momentum=0.9,epsilon=1e-5))
        D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

        D.add(Flatten())
        D.add(Dense(1))
        D.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

        print('D:')
        D.summary()

        return D

    def generator(self,config):

        G = Sequential()

        G.add(Dense(input_dim=config.z_dim, units=config.gf_dim*8*4*4))
        G.add(Reshape((4,4,config.gf_dim*8)))
        G.add(BN(momentum=0.9,epsilon=1e-5))
        G.add(ReLU())

        G.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=config.gf_dim*4,strides=2,padding='same',kernel_size=5))
        G.add(BN(momentum=0.9,epsilon=1e-5))
        G.add(ReLU())

        G.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=config.gf_dim*2,strides=2,padding='same',kernel_size=5))
        G.add(BN(momentum=0.9,epsilon=1e-5))
        G.add(ReLU())

        if config.dataset not in ['mnist','lines']:
            #more layers could (and should) be added in order to get correct output size of G

            G.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=config.gf_dim,strides=2,padding='same',kernel_size=5))
            G.add(BN(momentum=0.9,epsilon=1e-5))
            G.add(ReLU())

        G.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=config.c_dim,strides=2,padding='same',kernel_size=5))
        G.add(Activation('tanh'))

        print('G:')
        G.summary()

        return G


    def train(self,config):

        if config.dataset == 'mnist':
            (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = load_mnist()
            X_train = (X_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
        elif config.dataset == 'lines':
            (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = load_lines()
        elif config.dataset == 'celebA':
            (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = load_celebA()

        D_optim = Adam(learning_rate=config.learning_rate, beta_1=config.beta_1)
        G_optim = Adam(learning_rate=config.learning_rate, beta_1=config.beta_1)
        loss_f = 'binary_crossentropy'

        #Compile models
        self.D.compile(loss=loss_f,optimizer=D_optim)
        self.D.trainable = True
        self.G.compile(loss=loss_f,optimizer=G_optim)
        self.GAN.compile(loss=loss_f,optimizer=G_optim)



        batches = int(len(X_train)/config.batch_size)       #int always rounds down --> no problem with running out of data

        counter = 1

        print('\n' * 1)
        print('='*42)
        print('-'*10,'Training initialized.','-'*10)
        print('='*42)
        print('\n' * 2)
        
        start_time = time.time()
        for epoch in range(config.epochs):
            for batch in range(batches):

                batch_X_real = X_train[int(batch*config.batch_size/2):int((batch+1)*config.batch_size/2)][np.newaxis].transpose(1,2,3,0)
                batch_z = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(config.batch_size,config.z_dim))
                batch_X_fake = self.G.predict(batch_z[0:int(config.batch_size/2)])
                batch_X = np.concatenate((batch_X_real,batch_X_fake),axis=0)
                
                
                batch_yd = np.concatenate((np.ones(int(config.batch_size/2)),np.zeros((int(config.batch_size/2)))))
                batch_yg = np.ones((config.batch_size))

                #maybe normalize values in X?


                #Update D network
                self.D.trainable = True
                D_loss = self.D.train_on_batch(batch_X, batch_yd)

                #Update G network
                self.D.trainable = False
                G_loss = self.GAN.train_on_batch(batch_z, batch_yg)

                #Update G network again according to https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow.git
                #G_loss = self.GAN.train_on_batch(batch_z, batch_yg)

                # Ta tid på körningen

                # print("[%8d Epoch:[%2d/%2d] [%4d/%4d] time: %4.4f, d_loss: %.8f, g_loss: %.8f" \
                #   % (counter, epoch, config.epoch, idx, batch_idxs,
                #     time.time() - start_time, errD_fake+errD_real, errG))

                #Save losses to vectors in order to plot


                #Print status and save images for each config.sample_freq iterations
                if np.mod(counter,config.sample_freq) == 0:


                    print('Epoch: {}/{} | Batch: {}/{} | D-loss {} | G-loss {} | Time: {}'.format(epoch+1,config.epochs,batch+1,batches,D_loss,G_loss,time.time() - start_time))


                counter += 1

        print('\n' * 2)
        print('='*38)
        print('-'*10,'Training complete.','-'*10)
        print('='*38)
```

The program runs slow, but if you try running it using this chunk of code:

```
#import model
from setup import model_config


#create configuration object
config = model_config(dataset='mnist',loadmodel=False, interpolation=False,epochs=20,batch_size=64,
                        z_dim=100,gf_dim=64,df_dim=64,gfc_dim=1024,dfc_dim=1024,
                        c_dim=1,sample_freq=10) # >> model=None << ny parameter!


if config.loadmodel:
    # Pass model to model parameter in config, vet inte hur man gör
    # model1 = LoadModel('Generator')
    # model2 = LoadModel('Discriminator')
    # model3 = LoadModel('DG')
    #load existing model
    pass 
else:
    dcgan = dcgan(config)
    dcgan.train(config)

if config.interpolation:
    #do interpolation
    pass
```

it will start printing out progress and losses. I am certain there is some obvious error somewhere! If I have missed something, let me know what I can add in order to make this a better post!